# One-shot request single result in Room Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-mvvm

I am practicing my android skills (beginner) by coding a grocery list app. I have two tables in my db, a `shopping_item` table (The items I want to buy) and a `reference_item` table (The items I know the category and the unit price). Each time I add a shopping item, there is an `refId` field referencing to the reference item id corresponding. It is a default value to a default reference item if the shopping item is not referenced yet.

I use a MVVM model. I then have a `DAO`, a `repository`, a `viewModel` and my `fragments` that display data.

When I add a new shopping item, I want to know if there is a corresponding reference item. I want to do the following `Query`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT refId FROM reference_items WHERE reference_item_name = :refName")
suspend fun getRefItem(refName : String) : Int
```

It returns the id of the reference item corresponding as an Int or is null if it is not referenced yet. In my repository, I have a function like that:

```
suspend fun getRefItem(refName : String) = db.getShoppingDao().getRefItem(refName)
```

For now, I think I am doing alright. No mistake in sight I guess.

The problem begin when I try to implement my `viewModel`. What should I do? What about my `fragment`?

I have a `addNewItem(name: String, amount: Int)` function in my `fragment` to add the new item. I can find the reference item corresponding with the `name` provided.

I tried multiple things, using `LiveData`, `suspend` functions, `mutableLiveData`/`LiveData`, but I am getting lost right now. Every tutorials or examples use `LiveData` or Query all data from the db. I just want one `Integer`, one Time, no need of `LiveData` I think.

Answer (score 2):

here is the complete solution. Hope this is useful for you.

DAO

```
@Query(value = "SELECT refId FROM reference_items WHERE reference_item_name = :refName")
suspend fun getRefItem(refName : String) : Int
```

Repository

```
// Specify return datatype as Int
suspend fun getRefItem(refName : String): Int = db.getShoppingDao().getRefItem(refName)
```

ViewModel

```
fun getRefItem(name: String): LiveData<Int> {
   val result : MutableLiveData<Int>()  <-- setup livedata to return as value
   viewModelScope.lanuch {
      result.postValue(repository.getRefItem(name))
   }
   return result  <-- return livedata
}
```

Fragment

```
fun addNewItem(name: String, amount: Int) {
   // setup viewModel observer
   viewModel.getRefItem(name).observer { viewLifecycleOwner, { value ->
         // GET YOUR INT VALUE HERE 
         Log.i("VALUE", value) 
      }

   }
}
```